# Eclipse debugger freezes but gives no errors

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging someones code, and it freezes when I do something specific, but Eclipse doesn't stop on an error (I may have accidentally turned this off). When I press pause in the debugger, Eclipse shows me a bunch of suspended threads, where two of them are coloured red.
I want to find out if there is an error anywere, or if there's just an infinite loop somewhere (which doesn't seem likely, because Eclipse should break in the loop in that case).
I'd be great if anyone can help me with this Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give more information such as what language you're using.  If you're creating threads yourself, etc

Comment: Sure. I'm using Java, and the code I use definitely uses threads. Problems is that it's kind of a big, not properly organized (nor documented) project, so I have to delve pretty deep into the code to find where exactly the threads are created (I think the last time I saw threads are used to load in the library asynchronously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a deadlock?

You can use jconsole (goes with java jdk) to find out this. Launch jconsole, attach to your process, go to the Threads tab. Press "Detect deadlock"... It can be also useful to look at all threads states, for example you can have infinity loop in one thread and another thread blocked etc...

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try this now. (Sorry for the late reply, I did solve the problem in the code, but I've ran into the same problem for another bug, where the program freezes seemingly without direct reason)

Comment: Indeed, I found a deadlock! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before, try inserting breakpoints every few lines of code, then stepping through those until it breaks, removing the breakpoints that don't have any errors between them. Remember the line of code that causes it to crash and make whatever changes are necessary to fix it.

Comment: I'm gonna try this because I don't have any alternative, but I doubt it'll work. For small programs it definitely would, but this is a project with over 20,000 lines of code... The worst part is that the class and call diagrams are a huge mess and the program crashes upon pressing a button under certain conditions, so that wouldn't be easy to step through to.

Comment: that's a bunch of code, I would segjust starting the event that causes it to crash, like on load if that's when it crashes.

Comment: Hah, why didn't I think of that? Thanks! :)